# why isn't my php query working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've looked everywhere and have no idea why my query wont work!

```
<table>
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","pass","database");

    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT role FROM dicetrack");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<tr><td>" + $row["role"] + "</td></tr>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>
```

Im trying to record dice roles from different users.  Everything seems to work fine but when i test the query in any way possible, it comes out to fail.  Does anyone know what i did wrong? I've checked all spelling like 10 times and still cant find anything.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you want to do math here `echo "<tr><td>" + $row["role"] + "</td></tr>";`, or do you? ;-)

Comment: thanks, im thinking javascript.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` takes two parameters: the mysqli connection and your query:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT role FROM dicetrack");
```

should be:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT role FROM dicetrack");
```

You need to [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) as PHP would throw an error explaining this to you.

Comment: This was the first correct answer ;-) by yes... 13 seconds. I lucked out... again!

Comment: thanks, ill accept this one

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT role FROM dicetrack");
```

You didn't specify the connection.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT role FROM dicetrack");
```

Correct one.

Comment: wow... dont i feel dumb.... thanks